# Javascript window does not disappear?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a delete button in react that when clicked, my deleteHandler() is fired and the window comes up however when I try to click outside the window it doesnt disappear?
So the user is forced to refresh the page to cancel the delete functionality.

```
  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
if (window.alert('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
  dispatch(deleteCoin(id));
  alert(`Coin of Lot# ${id} deleted successfully.`);
}


};
```

Comment: That's the behavior of `alert()`, you can't close it by clicking outside of the alert box. `confirm()` or some other alert based library seems more appropriate for this

Comment: If I have a Alert component, how can I logically render the Alert component before dispatching the delete function?

Comment: You can use a modal rather than an alert

Answer (score 1):

try this!!

```
const deleteHandler = (id) => {
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
  dispatch(deleteCoin(id));
  alert(`Coin of Lot# ${id} deleted successfully.`);
}
};
```